# Python: Coordinates Boxes around Polyline

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have the following problem. I have a numpy array of coordinates (entry 0 to 2) and want to define all the coordinates of small boxes between pairs of my coordiante list instead of creating a huge box around the minimum and maximum of all my coordinates in the list. The boxes should have a range of 5 around the coordinate pairs for example.

My list for example looks like:

```
[[  24.313  294.679    1.5      1.       0.   ]
 [  25.51   295.263    1.5      2.       0.   ]
 [  26.743  294.526    1.5      3.       0.   ]
 ..., 
 [  30.362  307.242   10.779   95.       0.   ]
 [  29.662  307.502   10.38    96.       0.   ]
 [  29.947  308.99    11.147   97.       0.   ]]
```

My first idea is to calculate the minumum and maximum of each pair and use itertools.product to create the coordinates for the small boxes. So i want to have a box around  `24.313  294.679    1.5` and `25.51   295.263    1.5`, next a box aorund `25.51   295.263    1.5`  and  `26.743  294.526    1.5` and so on. For better understanding, i want the coordinates like here, but in 3D of course:

[image]

And not like here:

[image]

Is there any easy numpy, scipy approach to do this?

Comment: The image of your desired output is not consistent with the text of your request. Which on is it? Do you want a "tube" of constant width around your data series (image) or do you want the bounding boxes for successive pairs of data points in your series (text)?

Comment: I want the bounding boxes around the data points for successive pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

# create some data; in 2D so we can plot stuff
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10)
y = np.sin(x)
data = np.c_[x,y]

# --------------------------------------------------
# core bit: get boxes
# bboxes = np.array([data[:-1], np.diff(data, axis=0)]).transpose([1,2,0]) # shorter but with negative widths, etc
data_pairs = np.array([data[:-1], data[1:]])
minima = data_pairs.min(axis=0)
maxima = data_pairs.max(axis=0)
widths = maxima-minima
bboxes = np.array([minima, widths]).transpose(1,2,0)
# --------------------------------------------------

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], 'ko')
for bbox in bboxes:
    patch = Rectangle(xy=bbox[:,0], width=bbox[0,1], height=bbox[1,1], linewidth=0., alpha=0.5)
    ax.add_artist(patch)

plt.show()
```

### with pads:

```
# padded boxes:
pad = 0.1
N, D = data.shape
correction = pad*np.ones((N-1,D))

padded = bboxes.copy()
padded[:,:,0] -= correction
padded[:,:,1] += 2*correction

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], 'ko')
for bbox in padded:
    patch = Rectangle(xy=bbox[:,0], width=bbox[0,1], height=bbox[1,1], linewidth=0., alpha=0.5, facecolor='red')
    ax.add_artist(patch)
ax.set_xlim(0-pad, 2*np.pi+pad)
ax.set_ylim(-1-pad, 1+pad)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ok this seems nice! But now the data points are the edges of the boxes, arent they? I need a greater box, so a radius has to be added. I think it could be added in the stept of your minima and maxima? This will lead to a overlapp of coordinates between the single boxes. But i think that could be solved with using the set function after calculating.

Comment: Added code for padding the calculated bounding boxes.

Comment: Ah thanks :), how would the code look like if doing it in 3D?

Comment: I wrote the code such that all relevant parts (getting the bounding boxes and padding them) are independent of the dimensionality of the data. Plotting will obviously only work in 2D (as implemented at least).

Comment: Hmm, i always get the error: "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (97,5) (2,5) "

Comment: I think i know what the problem is. The problem is, that i want to define ALL coordinates of the small boxes in a specific grid and not only the edges and plotting them. So like if the user set x to 0.9, y to 0.9 and z to 2, this should be the spacing of the grid of the small boxes.